# InvalidResponse at /qr/ Protocol Error: <, head

Tags: python, django, qr-code

Am trying to implement QR code authentication into my project. So this I used "django-qrauth" module. I followed every step mentioned in https://github.com/aruseni/django-qrauth, but am getting the below error.

------------------  ERROR STARTS ----------------------------------------

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.17.1:1111/qr/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'registration',
 'qrcode')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'registration.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\qrauth\views.py" in wrapper
  41.         return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\qrauth\views.py" in qr_code_page
  54.         request.user.id
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\redis\client.py" in setex
  918.         return self.execute_command('SETEX', name, time, value)
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\redis\client.py" in execute_command
  461.             return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\redis\client.py" in parse_response
  471.         response = connection.read_response()
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\redis\connection.py" in read_response
  339.             response = self._parser.read_response()
File "D:\USERS\Srikanth\Projects\Django Projects\taskman\redis\connection.py" in read_response
  118.                                   (str(byte), str(response)))

Exception Type: InvalidResponse at /qr/
Exception Value: Protocol Error: <, head
-------------------------------- ERROR ENDS --------------------------------

#settings.py
AUTH_QR_CODE_EXPIRATION_TIME = 600 # Ten minutes

AUTH_QR_CODE_REDIS_KWARGS = {
    "host": "192.168.17.1",
    "port": 1111,
    "db": 0,
}

#urls.py
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^qr/', include('qrauth.urls')),
    )
```

Can anyone tell what's happening.

Comment: It looks like you Redis returns HTML which is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have configured the same port for the Django server and the Redis server.

The Django server running on 192.168.17.1 port 1111 as evidenced by the `Request URL: http://192.168.17.1:1111/qr/` message in the debug output. Also, the Redis server configuration in `settings.py` specifies the same hostname and port:

```
AUTH_QR_CODE_REDIS_KWARGS = {
    "host": "192.168.17.1",
    "port": 1111,
    "db": 0,
}
```

So Django's redis client is connecting to the Django server, sending a redis request, and then receiving a HTML response which begins with a `<head>` tag. This is expected as it is the Django server that has been contacted.

You need to change your redis settings to set the port to the one that your redis server is listening on. By default this is port 6379, but you can check in the redis config file.